# PerlScript to take certain words from text file

Tags: perl

I have a text File with data such that:

```
#alstrong textert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ET ACTIVEX Microsoft Whale Intelligent Application Gateway ActiveX Buffer Overflow-1"; flow:established,to_client; file_data; **content:"8D9563A9-8D5F-459B-87F2-BA842255CB9A"**; nocase; **content:"CheckForUpdates"**; nocase; distance:0; pcre:"/<OBJECT\s+[^>]*classid\s*=\s*[\x22\x27]?\s*clsid\s*\x3a\s*\x7B?\s*8D9563A9-8D5F-459B-87F2-BA842255CB9A/si";reference:url,dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/repository/entry/modules/exploits/windows/browser/mswhale_checkforupdates.rb; reference:url,www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/789121; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2010562; classtype:web-application-attack; sid:2010562; rev:6; metadata:affected_product Windows_XP_Vista_7_8_10_Server_32_64_Bit, attack_target Client_Endpoint, created_at 2010_07_30, deployment Perimeter, signature_severity Major, tag ActiveX, updated_at 2016_07_01;)
```

I need to extract all words in the fields named "Content" and store them in another text file. I found this code in Perl (I have no experience with it), Is it extract all fields or only the first one?

```
#!/local/bin/perl5 -w
# Description:
# Extract bit-pattern from content-part of Snort-rules.
# Choose rules that have only one content-part.
# Store distinct patterns only.
# Choose length of shortest and longest pattern to store.
$rulesdir = "/hom/geirni/www_docs/research/snort202_win32/Snort/rules";
@rulefiles = `ls $rulesdir/*.rules`;
$camfile = "camdata.txt";
#
$minLength = 4; # Bytes
$maxLength = 32;
#
# Find content-part of rules
for $rulefile(@rulefiles){
    #
    open(INFILE, "<".$rulefile) or die
      "Can't open ".$rulefile."\n";
    @rules = <INFILE>;
    close(INFILE);
    #
    for $rule(@rules){
        #
        $contentParts = 0;
        #
        if($rule =~ /content:/){
            @parts = split(/;/, $rule);
            for $part(@parts){
                if($part =~ /content:/){
                    $content = $part;
                    $contentParts++;
                    # Remove anything before content-part
                    $content =~ s/^.*content:.*?\"//i;
                    # Remove anything after content-part
                    $content =~ s/\"$.*//g;
                }
            }
        }
        #
        # Store content-part
        if ($contentParts == 1){
            push(@contents, $content);
        }
    }
}
#
#
#
# Convert content-strings to hex. Store only distinct patterns
for $content(@contents){
    #
    $pipe = 0; # hex patterns are limited by pipes; |00 bc 55|
    $char = ""; # Current character in content; ASCII or hex
    $pattern = ""; # Content converted to hex
    #
    # Loop through current content-string
    for ($i=0; $i<=length($content)-1; $i++){ # -1 for newline
        #
        $char = substr($content, $i, 1);
        #
        # Control over pipes
        if($char =~ /\|/){
            if(!$pipe){
                $pipe = 1;
            }
            else {
                $pipe = 0;
            }
            next; # Skip to next character
        }
        #
        # Convert to lowcase hex
        if(!$pipe){ # ASCII-value
            $pattern .= sprintf("%x", ord($char));
        }
        else { # hex-value
            $char =~ s/ //; # Remove blanks
            $pattern .= "\l$char";
        }
    }
    #
    # Store converted pattern
    if((length($pattern) >= $minLength*2) &&
       (length($pattern) <= $maxLength*2)){
        $hexPatterns{$pattern} = "dummyValue"; # Keys will be distinct
    }
}
#
#
#
# Print patterns, that have no subsets, to file
open(OUTFILE, ">".$camfile) or die
  "Can't open ".$camfile."\n";
#
@patterns = keys %hexPatterns;
$count = 0; # Count patterns that are written to file
#
HEXLOOP:
for($i=0; $i<=$#patterns; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<=$#patterns; $j++){ # Search for subsets
        #
        next if($i==$j); # Do not compare a pattern with itself
        #
        next HEXLOOP if # Skip if subset is found
          ((length($patterns[$i]) <= length($patterns[$j])) &&
           ($patterns[$j] =~ /$patterns[$i]/));
    }
    print OUTFILE $patterns[$i]."\n";
    $count++;
}
#
close(OUTFILE);
#
#
#
# msg
print
  "\n".
  " Wrote ".$count." patterns to file: \"".$camfile."\"\n".
  "\n";
```

Comment: _Is it extract all fields or only the first one?_ - Did you try ?  ;)

Comment: Yes, the result seems mysterious, the hex result is not any of them.

Comment: `open(INFILE, "<".$rulefile)` : Can you give an example of a rule file?

Comment: @MSAKARIM - Your question is invalidated by the information in line 4 of the script.

Comment: @Armali Okay, sorry. What if I need some edit in this code to take all content parts.

Comment: If you want a Perl script, I'd rather take the one from Polar Bear than edit the above.

Comment: _to take all content parts_, perhaps drop the restriction `if ($contentParts == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I found this code in Perl (I have no experience with it)

Rather than a Perl script you dare not even read the comments of which, consider just to use:

```
grep -Po 'content:".*?"' <text >another_text
```

To remove `content:`, the quotes and the dashes, you can use:

```
grep -Po '(?<=content:").*?(?=")' <text | tr -d - >another_text
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.
excuse me for the following question, What if I need to "content and any other symbols"
Like This:

8D9563A98D5F459B87F2BA842255CB9A    
CheckForUpdates

then convert them all to Hex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - convert `8D9563A98D5F459B87F2BA842255CB9A` to hex? These are hex already. And how do you want to convert `CheckForUpdates` to hex?

Comment: I want the script if it finds hex words, output them as they are, but if it finds words such as "CheckForUpdates" converts them from ASCII to hex.

Comment: What about words like `DEAD` or `BEEF`? What do you consider them to be - _hex_ or _ASCII_?

Comment: I will put the Hex data between | | to distinguish between them, patterns inside | | leave it as it, else convert it from ascii to hex.

Comment: There are no _| |_ in your sample _text File with data_.

Comment: I will insert it, i observed that all files i have, has this mark | | except one.

Answer (score 1):

The following perl script extracts "content" data to screen (on line by line basis). To store data, redirect output into a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while( my $line = <> ) {
        my @array = $line =~ /content:"(.*?)"/g;
        say join "\t", @array;
}
```

Run the script as `script.pl filename`

Output

```
8D9563A9-8D5F-459B-87F2-BA842255CB9A    CheckForUpdates
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I can't understand. where is the input file that contains text?
Or you mean that I should replace this code part with a certain part of the code mentioned in the question?

Comment: You have mentioned that you have some text file. Give this filename as a parameter to the script and it will extract the information you interested in.

Answer (score 0):

@Armali
I want to edit this part in the code so that it can check again in the same line if there are other content Parts and also extract them and print them in different lines:

```
#
    if($rule =~ /content:/){
        @parts = split(/;/, $rule);
        for $part(@parts){
            if($part =~ /content:/){
                $content = $part;
                $contentParts++;
                # Remove anything before content-part
                $content =~ s/^.*content:.*?\"//i;
                # Remove anything after content-part
                $content =~ s/\"$.*//g;
            }
        }
    }
    #
    # Store content-part
    if ($contentParts == 1){
        push(@contents, $content);
    }
}
```

}